# Django test does not add coverage with AssertRaises

Tags: python, django, code-coverage, django-testing, django-tests

There two lines that are not being executed by django tests when they are called as self.assertRaises.

I am using: Python 3.6.9, Django 3, Coverage.

I have this class:

```
class AverageWeatherService:
    subclasses = WeatherService.__subclasses__()
    valid_services = {
        subclass.service_key: subclass for subclass in subclasses
    }

    @classmethod
    def _check_service(cls, one_service):
        if one_service not in cls.valid_services:
            logger.exception("Not valid service sent")
            raise NotValidWeatherFormException("Not valid service sent")
```

And I have a local API that is up in my pc.

Then I wrote this test:

```
def test_integration_average_temp_services_error(self):
    self.assertRaises
    (
        NotValidWeatherFormException,
        AverageWeatherService()._check_service,
        "MyFakeService",
    )
```

And although the test is successful with **assert raises properly used this test is not adding coverage** but If I call this method in a wrong way like this one:

```
def test_integration_average_temp_services_error2(self):
    self.assertRaises
    (
        NotValidWeatherFormException,
        AverageWeatherService()._check_service("MyFakeService")
    )
```

Then of course I get an error running the test because the exception is raised and not properly catched by assertRaises **BUT It adds coverage. If I run this test wrongly I have my code 100% covered.** If I use assertRaises as the first way these two lines are not being covered (According to coverage html).

```
logger.exception("Not valid service sent")
raise NotValidWeatherFormException("Not valid service sent")
```

Also If I execute the method as the first way, the logger exception is not shown in console and when I run tests as the second way I am able to visualize the logger.exception on the terminal.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it.

This is the workaround:

```
def test_integration_average_temp_services_error(self):
    with self.assertRaises(NotValidWeatherFormException):
        AverageWeatherService()._check_service("MyFakeService")
```